# Convert String Decimal ("anyValueD+anyValue) to Numeric Decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, decimal

I am new in Python programming, and now I use Python for study.
I read text file to get the data.
I got string value, for example "0.710000000000D+02".
And now, I have to convert this string value into float or decimal number, so I run:

> > val = float("0.710000000000D+02")

but, it failed.

And, I tried another solution as follows:

> > val = [float(x) for x in variable]

But failed also.

Actually, it's only an ordinary decimal value, for example: 1D-02 = 0.01
As simple like that. But I have no idea how to solve this problem in Python.

Anyone can help this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be in Scientific Notation. I had the same problem long time back. Try with

```
float('0.710000000000D+02'.replace("D", "E"))
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same way!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.
Just replace "D" to "e"

> > str.replace("D","e")

Not a sophisticated way, but it works!